# Logstash does not seem to be collecting data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Logstash does not seem to be collecting data

got my conf for a tutorial

```
input { stdin { } }

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "indexforlogstash"
                user => "elastic"
                password => "password"
 }
}
```

tried differed input syntax.

Answer (score 0):

With this configuration, I can run logstash, paste a test message and logstash prints the output to the terminal.

```
 input {
   stdin { codec => "json" }
 }
 output {
   stdout { codec => json}
 }
```

sudo -u logstash /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/stdin.conf --config.reload.automatic

```
{ "message": {
     "log": "succesful entry"
}
```

I'm guessing you configured stdin and wait for messages to appear, but you have to type or copy-paste them into the terminal. Other input plugins will be more useful.

The stdin plugin is documented here
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-stdin.html

The documentation, source code and gem are here

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-syslog.html

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-syslog

https://rubygems.org/gems/logstash-input-syslog

The syslog plugin can be installed with
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-

Your configuration should then start with

```
input {
  syslog {
```

Comment: I am trying to run a syslog server and I am still not getting any data

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-syslog.html

Comment: Use the syslog input plugin if you want to use logstash as syslog server. Install the plugin and configure it. Now you use stdin as input, this is anything you type into the terminal where logstashs is running, that is great as example only!